# Helm 3 delete deployment by deleting the namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Since Helm 3 is not using **tiller** anymore is it a valid way to delete a deployment by deleting its namespace?

Are there any unexpected side effects?

Answer (score 7):

Yes! By deleting the namespace you would delete all resources that lives inside it.

Helm 3 is not using Tiller anymore and stores deployment informations within Kubernetes Secrets. But Secrets as other Kubernetes objects will be deleted when its namespace got deleted.

The most common way for deleting Helm 3 resource would be to use [uninstall command](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_uninstall/):

```
helm3 uninstall RELEASE_NAME
```

I would never suggest you to delete whole namespace. Side effect would be losing everything inside it.